# Cheap/Budget VPS Host with IPV6

Tags: vps, ip-address, ipv6

I'm looking for a cheap/budget vps host supplying ipv6 ips. 
Any suggestions?
PS: By cheap/budget i mean no more than about $6usd per month. 
PS 2: The service can be unmanaged

Comment: https://www.linode.com/IPv6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.nbiserv.de offers VPS with native IPv6 starting at 2.60 Euro per month. I use it, and find it very good.

Answer (score 1):

burst.net does offer free IPv6 ..

http://burst.net/linvps.shtml

Comment: I have a vps with burst.net already, not bad but they won't assign a /96 range.

Answer (score -2):

If you're just missing IPv6, why don't you had it by yourself?

You could register for a tunnel at [sixxs](http://www.sixxs.net/) for exemple.

Comment: Indoor plumbing is always preferable to outdoor plumbing.